# BizTalk Mapping -- Translate only for specific Ship To

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-mapper, biztalk2006r2

I need to convert an input XML into EDI 850, only for a particular ship From ( SHIPPINGWAREHOUSEID or SHIPPINGSITEID ) . 
Please let me know how we can achieve this. Attached the input XML . [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hcb8I.png)

Comment: Can you give an example message and what you have tried so far?

Comment: Its based on "Ship From" the xml tag is "SHIPPINGWAREHOUSEID"

Comment: Below are few XML input elements ( I am not able to attach / paste the entire data)<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><WC_INTERSTORETRANSFERHEADEREDIENTITY><TRANSFERORDERNUMBER></TRANSFERORDERNUMBER><SHIPPINGADDRESSCITY></SHIPPINGADDRESSCITY><SHIPPINGADDRESSDESCRIPTION></SHIPPINGADDRESSDESCRIPTION><SHIPPINGWAREHOUSEID></SHIPPINGWAREHOUSEID><WC_INTERSTORETRANSFERLINEEDIENTITY><TRANSFERQUANTITY></TRANSFERQUANTITY></WC_INTERSTORETRANSFERLINEEDIENTITY></WC_INTERSTORETRANSFERHEADEREDIENTITY>

Comment: Please use the [edit] link below the question and add the information there, rather than in the comments.

Comment: Ok . I have added now . Please help .

Comment: You've added an image. That doesn't make it easy for people to help you. Please add it as text.  Also add what your expected output is, and how you've tried to map it

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve the value from, presumably, somewhere in the N1 Loop using xpath(), then a Decide Shape in the Orchestration.